# Save to XML via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml

Okay i could be doing this %100 wrong I'm having trouble With the PHP to XML I'm just trying to save the customer details.......(not trying to be secure yet just learning how to do it)

The Html is a simple form
for firstname, lastname, password, email, and optional phone number  (not needed at the moment)

The PHP code is initiated after the javascript calls it by the Javascript..

PHP

```
<?php
            // header('Content-Type: text/xml');
                session_register('Customer');
                //session_start('customer'); 
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load('customer.xml');

            $firstname = $_GET["firstName"];
            $lastname = $_GET["lastName"];
            $email = $_GET["email"];
            $password = $_GET["password"];

            $MDA = $_SESSION["Customer"]; //assign the session varaible to MDA


            if (isset($firstname)) {
            $customerArray = array();
            $customerArray['firstname'] = $firstname;
            $customerArray['lastname'] = $lastname;
            $customerArray['email'] = $email;
            $customerArray['password'] = $password;
            $MDA[$firstname] = $customerArray;
            $_SESSION["Customer"] = $MDA;
                ECHO (toXml($MDA)); 
            }


            function toXml($MDA)
            {                    
                $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
                $Customer = $doc->createElement('Customers');
                $Customer = $doc->appendChild($Customer);
                $root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('Root'));

                foreach ($MDA as $a => $b)
                {
                    $nodeA = $doc->createElement('NodeA');
                    $root->appendChild($nodeA);
                    $nodeA->appendChild($attr1);
                    $attr1 = $doc->createAttribute('firstname');
                    $attr1->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($a['firstname']));

                $attr = $doc->createElement('firstname');
                $attr = $Customer->appendChild($person);

                $lastname = $doc->createElement('lastname'); 
                $lastname = $person->appendChild($lastname);   
                $value = $doc->createTextNode($a);
                $value = $lastname->appendChild($value);

                $email = $doc->createElement('email');
                $email = $person->appendChild($email);
                $value2 = $doc->createTextNode($b['email']);
                $value2 = $email->appendChild($value2);

                $password = $doc->createElement('password');
                $password = $person->appendChild($password);
                $value3 = $doc->createTextNode($b['password']);
                $value3 = $password->appendChild($value3);        
              }

                $doc->formatOutput = true; 
                $strXml = $doc->saveXML();
                //$doc->save('customer.xml'); 
                return $strXml;
            }
        ?>
```

and not to sure if its needed but the javascript... it just checks the password atm

```
var xHRObject = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
            xHRObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


        function test() 
        {
            var firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            var lastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            var number = document.getElementById("pNumber").value;
            var type = "";
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
              xHRObject.open("GET", "testregristation.php?", true);
              xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
                    if (password != password2) {
                    alert("Password is wrong");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("test " +firstname + " " +  lastname + " " + email + " : " + password);
                       document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;
              }
              xHRObject.send(); 
        };
        }
```

Comment: So.. what is the error?

Comment: its not saving the specific information to my XML :| and i don't know what or why

Comment: Are the variables filled? Is customerArray created? Try to loop through your code step by step and see where it breaks

Comment: i feel it may be the toXml function or it could be where the javascript is opening, its not sending the right form data...?

Comment: please do not post *live code* you currently write just copy & pasted from your project. Instead *isolate* the issue and create a new, self-containing example from scratch with as little data and code as necessary to show the concrete issue you have *a programming question* with. Otherwise this tends to become debugging and that is too limited for a Q&A site like Stackoverflow.

Comment: well thats my problem if i knew where to isolate it, or where the problem was i could fix it, I'm not to sure how the xml works so I'm unsure if its the javascript section or the php section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of date Browser issue, This works fine in Firefox